# Cap product in De Rham cohomology?

Tags: differential-topology, homology-cohomology, differential-forms

Suppose that $\omega$ is a differential form on a smooth compact manifold $X$, and let $V$ be a compact submanifold of the same dimension to the form.

Then we can define a fundamental class $[V]$*, and cap it with $\omega$ to an element of $H_0(X;\mathbb{Z})$, which we can associate with a number $\mathbb{Z}$, essentially by counting the number of points.

(*I think just class associated to a triangulation of $V$ -- I'm working with complex varieties, which can be triangulated anyway.)

Alternatively, we can restrict $\omega$ to $V$ and then integrate.

I guess these numbers should be the same, but I don't understand the cap product well enough to prove it. Maybe someone can suggest a hint or a reference?

Moreover, if $[V]$ is just some homology class of $X$, can it be represented by objects on which it is possible to integrate the restriction of $\omega$? (Not necessarily a manifold, but for example a union of manifolds that might overlap, or something...) If so, same question in this case.

Comment: Can you explain your definition of cap product? How do you "cap it with $\omega$"? As for your second question, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1489/cohomology-and-fundamental-classes

Comment: @user31415 The cap product uses a $q$-cochain to contract a $p$-simplex to a $p-q$ simplex, by evaluating $q$ on the first $q$ coordinates of $p$. $\sigma \cap \psi = \psi(\sigma|_{[v_0, \ldots, v_q]}) \sigma|_{[v_q, \ldots, v_p]}$. Writing that down I guess that under the identifications of DeRham and Singular cohomology, and by the construction of integration of a differential form on a manifold by breaking it up into charts (simplexes in our case), the two numbers should "obviously" agree. Though maybe I am mistaken? I think "cap product" just scares me for some reason - topology trauma.